# Trouble Taking a company name from one table an inserting it to another

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a table full of company names, the problem I am having is that it is full of duplicates.

To resolve this I am using the following piece of code to remove the data from one table and then insert it in to another using DISTINCT.

When i run the code, i keep getting the following error,

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Group Holdings Ltd')' at line 4

If i remove the company name variable it inserts all of the ip address fine, but as soon as i try to insert a company name i get the above error.

```
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT ip_address, company_name, FROM companydetail1";      
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  $ip_address = $row['ip_address'];
  $company_name = $row['company_name'] ;
  mysql_real_escape_string($company_name);
  mysql_real_escape_string($ip_address);

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO companydetail30 (ip_address, company_name) VALUES ('$ip_address', '$company_name') ") or die(mysql_error());
   }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is the error on the insert? You wouldn't have this issue if you used mysqli/PDO and prepared statements

Comment: Doing it this way, you have to escape your data before submitting it back to the database. Alternatively, you could use INSERT INTO ...SELECT instead

Comment: If the SELECT query delivers exactly the data that you want, then you shouldn’t muck about with PHP in the first place, but use the [INSERT SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax straight away …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only does your code not work in its current state, it is also vulnerable to SQL injection because you are using **mysql_real_escape_string** incorrectly.

The **mysql_real_escape_string** function gives back the escaped string as its *return value*, so you need to assign it back to the variable to save the escaped string:

```
$company_name = mysql_real_escape_string($company_name);
$ip_address = mysql_real_escape_string($ip_address);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your query with distinct there ia an error

```
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT ip_address, company_name, FROM companydetail1";
```

there is a "," after company_name it should not be

query should be like this

```
       $query = "SELECT DISTINCT ip_address, company_name FROM companydetail1";
```

Secondly you should do like this.

```
       $company_name = mysql_real_escape_string($company_name);
       $ip_address = mysql_real_escape_string($ip_address);
```